# Send date-value to input-field using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to add a date-value to an input-field on a website using selenium using the following code:
(at first i am switching to the iframe, input some other values and press a button - but on the new site this is not working anymore)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
  checkLink = "https://www.skatteetaten.no/person/avgifter/bil/eksportere/regn-ut/"

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)           

  driver.get (checkLink)       
  time.sleep(1)          
  waitWD.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iFrameResizer0']")))      
  time.sleep(1)        
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="Regnummer"]'))).send_keys("VH77934")  
  time.sleep(1)          
  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Neste"]'))).click()                 
  time.sleep(1)  
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="DatoEksporteringFraNorge"]'))).send_keys("30.11.2023")  

  driver.quit()
```

But i allways get this error:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\csgoenterprise\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="DatoEksporteringFraNorge"]'))).send_keys("30.11.2023")
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.89)
```

How can i add the date to this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `ElementNotInteractableException` as far as you rely on wrong input. Input with id `DatoEksporteringFraNorge` is hidden (and I guess it represents date picker), so it doesn't have size or location. It's truly not interactable - you can't send actions to it directly.

Visible input field has css locator `input[class*=form-control]`

```py
waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class*=form-control]')))
.send_keys('30.11.2022')
```

Comment: Seems to work grat - thanks a lot.
I am not familiar with CSS-selectors.
What does this class*= mean?
(an exact match for "form-control")?

Comment: @Rapid1898 element with tag input that contains class part form-control. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Comment: Ah i see - thx a lot